# Should you focus on keywords with the highest volume or keywords you already rank first page for?

Tags: seo, keywords, ranking, google-ranking

Should focus on keywords with 22,200 searches per month, but for which I only rank 44th, or should I focus on keywords with 480 searches per month, but for which I already rank 7th?

Comment: Are you chasing keywords? That is sooooo 2008. Those days are over! Focus on your content and then worry about the keywords that naturally show up in your writing. Search engines are semantic these days. You can plan your content around topic theme pyramids and of course pay attention to search terms used to find that content, but chasing keywords has become a bit of a fools errand these days.

Comment: I would believe that, except the singular and plural of some keywords have wildly different rankings.

Comment: I am not sure where you are getting that. Search engines know the difference and search by user intent determined using linguistic analysis and then by search history. If you are using a website for keyword analysis- stop. The only one I trust is Google Trends. The rest are junk and are designed to keep you chasing a dream that only they can sell the solution to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always had much better luck ranking for tail terms *first*.   It is very hard for a newer site to rank for competitive high traffic terms.   My sites have typically grown into head terms over the course of years.

Focus on creating content that contains both the head terms and lots of auxiliary tail terms.  You'll rank for the tail terms first, but eventually move to being competitive for the head terms.